# Are red flag methods bad?

Tags: exception, smalltalk, flags, squeak

In Squeak System Browser some `messages` have a red flag on left side.

I saw from the Balloon message that it is because I have an interruption in the code, that is a `self halt: 'foobar'` or a `self error:'foobar'`.

Is this so bad ? How can avoid it ? I put the `error` message where something particularly bad happened and going further makes no much sense. Like a failure in authentication, a failure on getting data from the networks and so on.

I would like to do something like rising an exception in these particular occasions, but, if possible, I don't want to see red flags on half of my methods.

Is there a standard practice to do it ?

Answer (score 3):

### Halts

A `#halt` is something you use for debugging purposes. In most of the cases, you insert a `#halt` when you want to reach a point in the execution flow and continue from there using the debugger, stepping and inspecting the involved objects. You can also want to add a `#halt` to see whether certain method gets invoked or not, so to better understand what's actually happening when you evaluate some expression. In all these cases the `#halt` should be removed as soon as your debugging finished.

As a typical example, imagine you are debugging an algorithm and you need to better understand why it fails. Then you insert a `#halt`:

```
computeDiagonal: k
  | product akk diff |
  product := self dotProductLimitedTo: k withRow: k.
  akk := matrix atRow: k column: k.
  diff := akk - product.
  diff < 0.0 ifTrue: [
    state := #fail.
    ^self halt].                                                       "wait a minute!"
  lower atRow: k column: k put: diff sqrt
```

### Assertions

There are cases, however, where your investigation wasn't conclusive enough, or the issue you are analyzing is not reproducible. It would then be a good idea to leave some longer-term indication that something should not be happening, or if it does, offer an opportunity to better understand its cause. In these situations a `halt` could work but may not be expressive enough (you are no longer immersed in the original problem) so you might want to consider and `#assert:` or `#deny:` instead. These messages, which are usually sent in unit tests, can also be present in any method and will convey a clearer intention.

Note that the decision to use `#halt` or `#assert:` doesn't depend on the method, but on the state of maturity of your model. For instance, if you aren't quite sure the algorithm won't fail again, but you cannot reproduce a failure, you should replace the `#halt` with an `assert:` or `#deny:`

```
computeDiagonal: k
  | product akk diff |
  product := self dotProductLimitedTo: k withRow: k.
  akk := matrix atRow: k column: k.
  diff := akk - product.
  self deny: diff < 0.0.                                              "got you!"
  lower atRow: k column: k put: diff sqrt
```

### Errors

Finally, if you are pretty sure something should/shouldn't happen, `#error:`: is your best choice. The difference between `halt`, `assert:` and `error:` is that the latter is for end users while the others are for developers.

```
computeDiagonal: k
  | product akk diff |
  product := self dotProductLimitedTo: k withRow: k.
  akk := matrix atRow: k column: k.
  diff := akk - product.
  diff < 0.0 ifTrue: [self error: 'Cholesky decomposition failed'].   "Oh oh..."
  lower atRow: k column: k put: diff sqrt
```

Of course, to take full advantage of the `Exception` framework, you might want to consider adding your own version of the `#error:` message, so that it would signal a specific subclass of `Exception`, rather than the generic one. There are plenty of examples in the system for you to get inspiration. This is not always necessary (or good), it is just something to think about.

Note also that an `Error` may be resumable, so do not associate them with aborting strategies. In fact, `#halt` and `#assert:` do signal resumable exceptions.

### Conclusion

The debugger is your best friend, and the the #`halt` message will bring it anywhere in your code. However, leaving a `#halt` in code that has been published will be interpreted as an indication of unfinished work.

Assertions may help other developers to better understand how to use your objects. But please, resist the temptation of being too assertive.

Errors are an elegant way of declaring unexpected behavior in a way that would allow the developer (you) to have a clue on what might have happened. Don't think of errors as text messages, errors in Smalltalk are first class objects that may contain valuable information.

Comment: thank you for the very detailed explanation Leandro.

Answer (score 2):

As you have figured out the *red flag* means there is some kind of `halt` in the message.  This is fine if you have a development code where you need to halt the execution to check the state.

That being said such code does not belong to a production code.  This should be replaced by **exceptions**.

In squeak the following exceptions (ANSI-Compatible Exceptions):

### Evaluating Blocks with Exceptions

**Methods for handling Exceptions raised in a BlockContext**

> - Message:    ensure: aTerminationBlock
> - Description:   Evaluate
>     aTerminationBlock after evaluating the receiver, regardless of whether
>     the receiver's evaluation completes.
> - Message:   ifCurtailed: aTerminationBlock
> - Description:  Evaluate the
>     receiver. If it terminates abnormally, evaluate aTerminationBlock.
> - Message:   on: exception do: handlerActionBlock
> - Description: 
>     Evaluate the receiver in the scope of an exception handler,
>     handlerActionBlock.

Examples

```
["target code, which may abort"]
    ensure:
        ["code that will always be executed 
            after the target code, 
            whatever whatever may happen"]

["target code, which may abort"]
    ifCurtailed:
        ["code that will be executed
            whenever the target code terminates 
            without a normal return"]

["target code, which may abort"]
    on: Exception
    do: [:exception |
            "code that will be executed whenever
            the identified Exception is signaled."]
```

The source of the information is [Squeak Smalltalk: Classes Reference](https://wiki.squeak.org/squeak/uploads/SqueakClassesRef.html#Exceptions).